# split a string using a open and close tag

Tags: c#, string, split

I wish to known if exist a clean way to split a string using different tags for opening and ending.

For example:

> <&field1&>outside<&field2&>

using the function split:

> ```
>         string[] dd={"<&","&>"};
>         string[] b1 = a1.Split(dd,StringSplitOptions.None);
> ```

it show me:

1. 0:
2. 1:field1
3. 2:outside
4. 3:field2
5. 4:

(that it is that i want to do).
but also

> <&field1<&outside<&field2<&

show the same.

Comment: For the second example, what should it show instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"\G<&(?<code>.*?)&>"
```

The TemplateParser in the AspCodeRegex class in System.Web.RegularExpressions uses something similar to this
(answer via @rexm)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regular expression to do this. After a quick play I came up with this which seems to match the entries within the `<& &>` delimiters, but you get the idea:

```
<&([^&]*)&>
```

See [Regular Expression Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kweb790z.aspx) for some more examples and also the code you need to run your regex.